# Node/Redis: Get all key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I simply want to get all key-value pairs.

```
redisClient.get('*', function (err, pairs ) {
    ...
});
```

Doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

I'm using the node_redis library (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis);

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: node_redis - see above.

Comment: i didn't see anything that allows a wild card query. you might try looking at this http://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: There is always the `KEYS` command which everyone since the dawn of Redis says is inefficient, but you can try that.

Comment: @Niloct is right. I don't think `GET` will work with a wildcard. I believe `redisClient.keys('*', ...)` is what you're looking for.